# How can I print the decimal representation of a character in c?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, binary

I am trying to figure out how to print the ascii value of a character in binary. Here is what I have done so far, but it does not work at all and I dont know why. Can someone of you C wizards help me??

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    char myChar;

    printf("Enter a character:\n");
    scanf("%c", &myChar);
    printf("Your character is %c\n", myChar);
    printf("ASCII in BIN: %c\n", toBinary(myChar));

    return 0;
}

char* toBinary(int decimalNumber) 
{
    char binaryValue[7] = "";
    for (int i = sizeof(binaryValue); i >= 0; ++i) 
    {
        int remainder = decimalNumber % 2; 
        decimalNumber = decimalNumber / 2;

        binaryValue[i] = remainder;
    }
    return &binaryValue;
}
```

Comment: You cannot return address of `binaryValue`, because it's local to `toBinary` and array no longer exists when function exits.

Comment: i>=0 and ++i together in for loop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%c` format string will always interpret the corresponding `printf` argument as a character. In this case, its probably not what you want.

```
printf("ASCII in BIN: %d\n", myChar);
```

will print out the ascii code point of `myChar` just by telling `printf` to treat it as a number.

If you'd like to print out the string being returned by your `toBinary` function, you can do that with

```
printf("ASCII in BIN: %s\n", toBinary(myChar));
```

There's a good reference of the various `%` codes and what they mean [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

---

However, it's also worth noting that your `toBinary` function probably doesn't do what you want. This loop condition:

```
for (int i = sizeof(binaryValue); i >= 0; ++i)
```

will start at `sizeof(int)` and count up until it runs out of integers, then stop only because `INT_MAX + 1 == INT_MIN`. Because you're using `i` as an array index, this will almost certainly crash your program.

You also need to make sure to terminate the string you're generating with a `'\0'`, as that is how subsequent calls to `printf` will recognize the string has ended.

And, as noted in other answers, your `toBinary` implementation is also returning a pointer to a memory address that will get automatically deleted as soon as `toBinary` returns.

Comment: Thanks! I understand what I made wrong with the printf and the for loop. However, how can I fix my `toBinary` function?

Comment: The string its generating should be passed in as a parameter rather than returned. That would solve the immediate deletion issue. Also, since you want a binary representation, and sizeof works in bytes, you'll need to multiply by 8 to get the right number of bits. Other than that, and the stuff noted in my answer, your basic algorithm is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("ASCII in BIN: %c\n", toBinary(myChar));
```

`%c` is to print a character.

And, there is no BOOL type in C, so you can change it in to a string, and pass the pointer to an array to `printf("%s", pointer)`

Answer (score 0):

You are returning address of local array.

This is both incorrect return type (char ** vs char *) and a bad thing to do at all.

Comment: ... so how can OP fix it?

Comment: Read more C tutorials definitely. I am not sure this is a good place to explain stuff like that.